# Has vs had grammaticality for something that happened last week

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect, time, perfect-aspect

In my English class, my professor posed the following question:

> Manuel (**has / had**) asked Pedro to help him fix his computer last week.

He said the answer was *has*, but that seems present tense to me, but he said that the “last week” part is entirely irrelevant. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have my doubts as to the validity of the question your professor asked you. His answer sounds wrong to my native ear.

That’s because you really don’t use present tense for something that happened last week. You normally just use past tense.

> 1. Manuel asked Pedro to help him fix his computer last week.

Compare that with the immediacy that present tense brings:

> 2. Manuel has only just now asked Pedro to help him fix his computer, so we’ll wait around a bit until Pedro  gets here.

The use of past perfect would need some narrative framework around it to justify the action being pushed even further backwards from the normal past:

> 3. I had *thought* that Manuel had already asked Pedro for help fixing his computer last week sometime, but it turns out that I was wrong about that: Manuel never mentioned it at all!

I don’t think your professor’s answer makes sense here.

Comment: I  thought that Manuel(had) already asked Pedro for help fixing his computer last week sometime, but it turns out that I was wrong about that: Manuel never mentioned it at all!   Is past perfect in your example mandatory because the events are all  in order and the sequence is clear

Comment: @user5577 "Mandatory"? No, probably not. It really is up to the narrator what "tone" he wants to convey. There are certainly many times in reported speech or related accounts that you see backshifting more for stylistic reasons than for any matter of strict ordering. ESL students are seldom taught about that, which provokes many questions when they encounter real examples from real speech; for example  [see here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2380). Then again, trying to impose strict-ordering rules will over-select for the past perfect compared with typical native-speaker use.